# JSON call to server from PhoneGap application - No response

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building my first PhoneGap application, just a proof-of-concept at the moment.

What I want to do is to perform an Ajax call (using JSONP) to retrieve a record from a database on a backend server. The code is working perfectly in the browser, but when I make an Android .apk using PhoneGap Build, that call is not doing anything.
The pages opens, and local Javascript works. I can even use localStorage.

But it seems like the application is not allowing my to communicate out to the Internet.

In config.xml I have added

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

as well as

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
</config-file>
```

Here is the relevant jQuery code which does the call:

```
var json = new Object();
var docunid =  $("#policyNumber").attr("data-docunid");
$("#statusInfo").html("Loading " + docunid + "...");
json["unid"] = docunid;
$.ajax({
     url: "http://www.example.com/websites/losscontrol/ajax_GetInspectionDetails.jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: json
});
```

When the code is executed, the message "Loading xxxxxxxx..." is being displayed, then nothing. In the browser it all works, the data is retrieved and the values displayed by the callback function.

What am I missing?

***Update:***
Thanks to Simon's comment I managed to solve it. The network guys had blocked the web server from external access without me knowing it.
So when I executed the code in the browser on my computer inside the firewall, it worked, but when the same URL was called from the PhoneGap application on my phone (and therefor outside the firewall) it simply did not work.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Do you have a Content Security Policy in your app?

Comment: No errors in the console (assuming you talk about when I access it through the web). I am using Firebug to check that.
I do not have a Content Security Policy, I googled it and will put one in now and test.

Comment: Update: I added <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"> to the HTML file, but I don't see any change. Still not loading.

Comment: Could you check for errors in the console on your android device? [Chrome Inspect](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=en) is my tool for stuff like this...

Comment: And about the CSP: You don't have to add one, it's a rather common error to have a false configured one, that's blocking your communication. So it was one of my first thoughts...

Comment: What happens if you fire up the browser on your device and try to open the JSON URL that your app is trying to access... can the browser see the remote resource?

Comment: That comment helped. I found out that the firewall is blocking access to that URL from the outside, but not from my computer at work. So in the browser it all worked because I was inside the firewall, but when I created the PhoneGap application and executed it on my phone, I came from the outside... 
When I am calling another URL on a publically accessable server, it works... Now on to beat up the network guys. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already done so, you need to install the Cordova [whitelist](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/whitelist/) plugin. This issue had me stumped for a while. There are other threads on here with the same problem.

Comment: I am trying to find some documentation on how to properly do that. Dobe does not have the whitelist amonmg the plugins they supply out-of-the-box, so I tried to add <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.whitelist" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git" source="git" /> in config.xml.
But I an not seeing any change. I already have <access origin="*"/> in the config.xml file...

Comment: Not sure about how to add a plugin to your project environment; I use VS2015 which adds them automatically. But in an older project I have, I just had (for example) <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" version="0.2.12" /> without the 'spec' and 'source' fields. Do any other plugins work OK? If not you could try the 'device' one which is easy to test.